# How to change appearance of figure window?

Tags: matlab

I happened to see a figure window on the internet as Fig. 2. How do I change the appearance of the figure window in MATLAB to darker background (Fig. 1), for example, instead of the default white one (Fig. 2)? I believe it's somewhere for user setting.

Fig. 1

[image: Fig. 1]

Fig. 2

[image: Fig. 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this.

- Right click on Figure 1, just outside of the plot, to open a context menu.  Select **Color** and chose the darker color square that you want your background to match.  (Works on MATLAB 2019.)
- Get the handle to your current figure and change background property directly.  You can use `gcf` to get the current figure's handle (the one most recently selected) and then set the background color using a vector containing the red, blue, and green values you want like so:

  - `set(gcf, 'color', [0.8, 0.8, 0.8]);`
- You can initialize a figure with the desired background color like so:

  - `f = figure('color', [0.8, 0.8, 0.8]);`

A black background color would be `[0, 0, 0]`.